# How much time did the technical part (motion capture) of the film Avatar consume?

Tags: production, avatar

I heard it took 11 years for the technical development for Avatar.  Is this true, or is the story development included in this calculation.  Can anybody confirm how long it took for the motion capture technology part alone?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_%282009_film%29) page (and yes, I understand that Wiki isn't foolproof), the screenplay was written in 2006 and the film was released in 2009.  It does state that Cameron had a vision of the movie as far back as 1994, and that at some point he felt technology wasn't advanced enough to do what he envisioned for the movie, but there's no indication that the production itself took 11 years.

Comment: And they lagged in technology. But the success of Lord of the rings movies may have inspired the director